# Why Opera and Google Chrome blocks the site if it is on remote server, but does not if it is on local server?

Tags: google-chrome, opera

Why Opera and Google Chrome blocks the site if it is on remote server, but does not if it is on local server?

If i run my website from local server, it is working on all browsers.
If i put it on remote server ( identical code ), the Opera and Chrome blocks the site. What could be the reason? I am getting the message :

From the Opera

```
This page isn’t working

Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards).
```

From Chrome :

```
This page isn’t working

Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards).
Try visiting the site's homepage.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR
```

The page contains only two input lines for an email, and for a notice. Also several hidden fields with htmlentities encoded strings.

The page was working on Android mobile before approx 10th July if served remotely from web-server, but now does not work on mobile too.

What implies, that it works from localhost, but does not work on remote server?

Answer (score 1):

he reason was term string having url:

```
foreach($termArr as $term ) {
    $termStr .= '<a href="'.$termUrl.'/params?termPath='.$term['path'].'&policyN='.$term['title'].'" target="_blank">'.$term['title'].'<a>,';
}
```

During the payment , i was displaying  a string containing url as  a part of form i was submitting.
I check on server side every input, thus no way xss can pass.
But Opera and Chrome detects url in the form as malcode.

Maybe there are other reasons, but after removing the `term urls`, i get form working and page loading.